# Attaching a Path to a userform selection

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook in E:\EXPENCES. In it, a Userform with 2 comboboxes.
cmb1 lists names of workbooks that are in a different folder (E:\MLDOWNLOADS) - The Target.
cmb2 lists Sheets in the current workbook - The Destination.
I would like to copy a range from Target and paste into the destination.
How do I assign  a variable that contains full path of target attached to cmb1.value

current code:

```
Dim cbook As Workbook
Dim psheet As Worksheet
Dim wsDest As Worksheet
Dim lCopyLastRow As Long
Dim lDestLastRow As Long
Dim Dpath As String

  
  Dpath = "E:\MLDOWNLOADS\"
  
  cbook = (Dpath & Frmdownloads.cmb1.Value)
  psheet = Frmdownloads.cmb2.Value
  
  Set wsCopy = Workbooks(cbook).Worksheets("List transactions")
  Set wsDest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(psheet)
 
  lCopyLastRow = wsCopy.Cells(wsCopy.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
 
  lDestLastRow = wsDest.Cells(wsDest.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

  wsCopy.Range("A2:D" & lCopyLastRow).Copy wsDest.Range("A" & lDestLastRow)
End Sub
```

Comment: You might set up the Target Cbx with 2 columns, one of them hidden and containing the path. You could then simply combine the path from one column with the name from the other. Read up on how to create and read from multi-column combo boxes. Also, please consider clear and consistent variable naming. *Target* and *Destination* appear on the same end of the arrow. Try *Source*, and having decided on *Source* don't call it *Copy*. Also: `cbook` and `psheet` are declared as objects. You must use the `Set` statement when assigning values to them.

Comment: Thanks for that, shall amend accordingly and try..